# Does .NET Reactor support protecting MEF (System.Addin) application?

Tags: c#, obfuscation

I tried .NET Reactor with a simple Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) application. The host couldn't load adpators and addins.

There is no forum support from .NET Reactor, so stackoverlow seems the best place to ask this question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the specificity of your issue you should consider contacting Eziriz directly, however as long as you don't obfuscate the metadata of the types exported everything should work fine. Mind that as soon as you'll obfuscate the metadata of a public type used elsewhere things will most likely break.